# Type ^Q in vim editor

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu

I need to replace ^Q, ^S and ^U in a text file with Ubuntu. These are ctrl+Q and not carat+Q . Since ^Q is a control key command, I cannot type that in and carat+Q does not work. Is there anyway to type in ^Q ^S and ^U

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an escape sequence for this.

For ^Q type Ctrl+V Ctrl+Q. On some system you have to type the code for it, eg: Ctrl+V 017.

Comment: That won't work for sequences trapped by the terminal emulator

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That is working fine. Thanks. what are the codes for ^S and ^U

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using Ctrl-V is to use digraphs.   A digraph is a two-character representation of a Unicode value, which can include control characters.  By default the digraph for `^Q` is `D1`, `^S` is `D3` and `^U` is `NK`.    To enter a digraph in insert mode press Ctrl-K followed by the digraph, e.g. to enter  use `<Ctrl-K>D1`.

The docs say you can also set the 'digraph' option and enter a digraph by pressing first character, backspace, second character. This does not appear to work for all control characters though.

You can use digraphs to enter a wide range of Unicode characters, and can redefine existing ones or define new ones.  Type `:digraph` to get a full list of currently defined digraphs and `:h digraphs` to see the full help.